# Turn off Tab to add new row to table using Google Docs App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

After pressing `TAB` button if the cursor is in the last column of last row
in `Google Docs` it creates a new row for the table. How to disable this using app script?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specifically prohibit a key, but you could limit the table to a certain number of rows by a function.
This function will check (frequency due to the trigger used) that no more than XYZ rows are available and if more, removes them.
Have a look:

```
function onOpen() {
  var t = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getTables()[0];
  var n = t.getNumRows();
  var maxRows = 3;
  while (n > maxRows) {
   t.removeRow(n-1);
   n = t.getNumRows();
  }
}
```

This will run, every time the doc gets opened. You could also use a time-trigger, so the function will check up to every minute/ hour/ day:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable